# Wrong webform submission ID

Tags: theming, webforms

I've got a view where I approve webform submissions, update a table column programmatically and send out e-mails through its tpl file. However, somehow I'm getting wrong and `$uid` and therefore e-mails go out to the wrong people.

I tried to debug this using `dpm()`, that's how I know I'm getting wrong values. I first thought I am setting variables in the wrong place but I doubt that because it's the same even though I changed the lines. Can you help me? Below are my codes for setting variables and sending out e-mails:

```
<?php

if(isset($approve))
{
  $uid=$submission->uid;
  $nid=$submission->nid;
  $sid=$_POST['sid'];
  $sponsorid=$_POST['sponsoruid']; 
  dpm("uid:".$uid);
  dpm("nid:".$nid);
  dpm("sid:".$sid);
  dpm("spid:".$sponsorid);
  if (empty($sponsorid))
  {
    $sponsorid=0;  
  }
  $url="/proje-basvurulari";
  $num_updated = db_update('webform_submissions') 
    ->fields(
      array(
        'approval' => '2',
        'sponsorid'=>$sponsorid,
      ))
      ->condition('sid', $sid, '=')
      ->execute();

  $date=date('d-m-Y', $submission->submitted);
  $fdetails = db_query("select * from {users} where uid=$uid")->fetchAll();
  $sdetails = db_query("select * from {users} where uid=$sponsorid")->fetchAll();
  dd($fdetails);
  dd($sdetails);


  foreach($sdetails as $s) {
    $semail=$s->mail;
    $sname=$s->name;
  }
  foreach($fdetails as $f)
  {
    #$femail=$f->mail;
    $fname=$f->name;
  }
  $femail = $submission->data['4']['0'];
  ...
  ?>
```

`$uid` and therefore `$fdetails` are set wrong. Isn't `$submission->uid` supposed to be the uid of whoever filled out the webform?